# is there a rspec built-in matcher for (===) operator?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I expect to write codes like:

```
range = (1..10)
regex = /[a-z]/

expect(range).to ===(5)
expect(regex).to ===('a')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use operators, use `be`:

```
describe :something do

  it 'works just fine' do
    expect((1..10)).to be === 5
  end

  it 'works fine too' do
    expect(/[a-z]/).to be === 'a'
  end

end
```

But there are more specific options, for Regex:

```
expect(/[a-z]/).to match('a')
```

And for Ranges:

```
expect(1..10).to cover(5)
```